# Sort files based on incomplete array of filenames

Tags: ruby

Given a directory with three files `fileA, fileB, fileC`, I can make an array of the order I want them sorted like so:

```
prio = [ "fileC", "fileA", "fileB" ]
#=> ["fileC", "fileA", "fileB"]
Dir.glob("*").sort_by { |i| [prio.index(i), i] }
#=> ["fileC", "fileA", "fileB"]
```

However, I'm trying to alphabetically sort anything else in the directory *after* those in the **prio** array, but as soon as I add a fourth file, I get:

```
Dir.glob("*").sort_by { |i| [prio.index(i), i] }
ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed
from (irb):3:in `sort_by'
from (irb):3
from :0
```

I have tried using `if prio.include?(i)` as a condition inside the block but then I get:

> TypeError: can't convert nil into Array from (irb):4:in `<=>'

I am using ruby-1.8.7. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it'd do it:

```
prio = %w[ fileC fileA fileB ]
files = %w[foo fileA bar fileB baz fileC]
prio_files = prio & files  # => ["fileC", "fileA", "fileB"]
non_prio = files - prio_files # => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
process_order = prio_files + non_prio # => ["fileC", "fileA", "fileB", "foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

If you want the `non_prio` files sorted use:

```
process_order = prio_files + non_prio.sort
```

See Array's [`-`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-2D) and [`&`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-26) for more information.

Comment: Good one, Sn. We had a mind-meld there. By the way, who's 'Donna'?

Comment: Array's use of sets makes some array manipulation really easy.

Comment: I was too subtle in mentioning the goal of *not* wanting to manually add files beyond those that are priority. However, I can use your example with `Dir.glob` and then remove those files that are in both arrays. Thanks!

Comment: "... the goal of not wanting to manually add files beyond those that are priority." Then you need to be not-subtle, and add those sort of requirements to the questions you ask. I'm not sure what you mean though. Do you want the code to automatically figure out the `prio` files? If so, that's easily done using a `select` or `grep`, but that would negate your ability to specify the order.

Comment: @theTinMan **alphabetically sort anything else in the directory after those in the prio array,** That meant I didn't want to hand create an array of non-priority files. So as I said in my previous comment, I used `Dir.glob` and subtract the priority files out.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit: I initially deleted my answer because it is essentially the same as @theTinMan's, which he had posted a couple of minutes before I posted mine. In light of your comment, however, I've undeleted it just to address your point specifically.]

Does this do what you want?

```
all_files = Dir.glob("*")
prio & Dir.glob("*") + (all_files-prio).sort
```

Comment: That is very close to what I did. `prio + (all - prio).sort`

Comment: That's fine, so long as you are certain all the files in `prio` are in the directory. In a production environment, if you expected all the `prio` files to be present, you might confirm that and raise an exception if any were missing. Then if they are all there, continue with what you have.